# Python while loop with input function and multiple condition checks

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am solving the following problem, and came across the situation where I'm unable to define either decision operators or the while loop properly.

**The task:**

Customers get a monthly discount depending on the length of contract they take out as shown below:

3 – 6 months        2% discount

7 – 12 months       5% discount

over 12 months      10% discount

The program should ask users for their name and the monthly cost of their game package. It should then ask them to enter the contract length they would like. The maximum contract length is 18 months. The program should finally display the entered details and the final cost of the package with the discount applied.

```
contract_length = 0
final_cost = 0

#prompt the user to enter their name
user_name = input("What is your name? ")

#prompt the user to enter monthly cost for the game package
package_cost = float(input("Monthly cost of your game package: "))

while contract_length > 0 and contract_length <= 18:

    #prompt the user to enter the contract length
    contract_length = int(input("Enter the contract length you would like: "))


    #selection statement to calculate final cost
    if contract_length > 12: 
        discount = (package_cost * 0.1)
        final_cost = format(package_cost - discount,".2f")

    elif contract_length > 6:
        discount = (package_cost * 0.05)
        final_cost = format(package_cost - discount, ".2f")

    elif contract_length >= 3:
        discount = (package_cost * 0.02)
        final_cost = format(package_cost - discount, ".2f")
    else:
        print("Invalid entry")


#display results
print("Name " +user_name)
print("Package Cost £",str(package_cost))
print("Months in Contract " , str(contract_length))
print("The final cost is £",str(final_cost))
```

**Error I am having**

```
What is your name? Jhon
Monthly cost of your game package: 35.12
Name Jhon
Package Cost £ 35.12
Months in Contract  0
The final cost is £ 0
>>>
```

I even tried "and" to "or" but with or operator it's start repeating the input function under while loop. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: the initial contract length is less than 0 so it will never enter the while loop because the condition is not satisfied

Comment: You also need to validate `package_cost`. Think about what is gonna happen if the user inputs a `package_cost <= 0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to have a condition on the final_cost, like this:

```
contract_length = 0
final_cost = 'none'

#...

while final_cost == 'none':

    #prompt the user to enter the contract length
    contract_length = int(input("Enter the contract length you would like: "))

    if contract_length > 18:
        print("Invalid entry")
        continue

    #selection statement to calculate final cost
    if contract_length > 12: 
        discount = (package_cost * 0.1)
        final_cost = format(package_cost - discount,".2f")

    elif contract_length > 6:
        discount = (package_cost * 0.05)
        final_cost = format(package_cost - discount, ".2f")

    elif contract_length >= 3:
        discount = (package_cost * 0.02)
        final_cost = format(package_cost - discount, ".2f")

    else:
        print("Invalid entry")
```

Comment: With your code amendment, I am getting this error now. while final_cost < 0:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: Thank you so much. Its working now. If user enter contract_length > 18, its printing invalid entry but still showing its all calculation. I tried to break after this statement but no succeeded.

Comment: I don't get it, what are you trying to do?

Comment: You just made the magic correction i.e. continue. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution:

```py
contract_length = 0
final_cost = 0
package_cost = 0
user_name = None

while not user_name:
    user_name = input("What is your name? ")

while package_cost <= 0:
    package_cost = input("Monthly cost of your game package: ")
    if not package_cost.isdigit():
        package_cost = 0
    package_cost = float(package_cost)

while not (3 <= contract_length <= 18):
    contract_length = input("Enter the contract length you would like: ")
    if not contract_length.isdigit():
        contract_length = 0
    contract_length = int(contract_length)

if contract_length > 12:
    discount = 0.1
elif contract_length > 6:
    discount = 0.05
elif contract_length >= 3:
    discount = 0.02
else:
    discount = 0

final_cost = package_cost - (package_cost * discount)

print("Name", user_name)
print("Package Cost £", format(package_cost, ".2f"))
print("Months in Contract", contract_length)
print("The final cost is £", format(final_cost, ".2f"))
```

Comment: Thank you.  It’s a very nice way too.

Comment: Thanks. If possible, mark one of the answers as accepted. That way you will help others with the same question.